# MVC routing with both ID and action at same level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'd like to be able to make a MVC route that has both an action and the ID at the same level.

Example:
If a call is made to

```
HTTP://www.something.com/F/GetMyData
```

then the action GetMyData is called

If the call is made to

```
HTTP://www.something.com/F/dfeTD53F
```

and no action is found with this name its assumed that "dfeTD53F" is an ID controller F should be called with that ID.

Is this possible and how?

Is this just bad application design?

Right now I have routes to all specific actions under F in my route.config, and that'll propably get quite messy in time.

Comment: you can put individual routing attributes on a specific controller or action method if it should behave differently to the normal rules. But "controller F should be called with that ID"...not sure what you mean. You can't just call a controller, you have to call a specific action method.

Comment: Well If I call controller F it invokes the Index action: The route for that is this:
           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Surveys",
                url: "s/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "s", action = "Index" }
            );

Comment: that'll be because you've modified your routing config then? Pretty sure that's not the default...but you didn't show the code so I didn't know.

Comment: Well, the question is not so much about what I have done but wether it is possible to have the action and the id at the same level and default to the ID if no corresponding action is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was creating a "catch all" route (as the final entry) and then handle it manually in the controller.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CatchAll",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults:  new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Its not an elegant solution, but well..  MVC routing isnt elegant to begin with.